# Eclipse (with Pydev) keeps throwing SyntaxError

Tags: python, eclipse, syntax, pydev

My code:

`print "Hello World!"`

I even tried adding a semicolon behind, but everytime I save and run (as Python run) it says:

> File "E:\Software\Eclipse\Workspace\Python1\src\main.py", line 1
>   print "Hello World!";
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for this thread! It's a so easy but still annoying problem when it dosen't work with a simple print! I used 3.xx and that's why print 'Hello World!' didn't work :P So all 3.xx use print("Hello World!") :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What version of Python are you using? Python 2.X has `print` as a keyword, but Python 3.X only has `print()` as a function - you'd need to use `print("Hello, World!")` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. Problem solved. Just curious, is it a must to have a semi-colon at the end of every line as in the case of PHP/Javascript? Hm, maybe I should have used the latest 2.X instead of 3.X, I thought 3.X would be better since it's newer.

Comment: Python does not require semicolons (and in fact discourages them).

Comment: For a more comprehensive list of differences, take a look at http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a longshot but - if you're running python 3.0 that is invalid syntax.  Try

```
print("Hello World!")
```

to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, indentation is really important... Have you check your indentation? Also, lose the `;` (don't need it).

correct:

`print("hello")`  or `print "hello"` (for < 3.0)

not correct:

`...print("hello")` or `print "hello"` (for < 3.0)

where `.` denotes spaces.

Comment: There are no spaces/tabs in front if that's what you mean.