# What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to use a `print` statement in Python, it gives me this error:

```
>>> print "Hello, World!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello, World!"
                        ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

What does that mean?

---

<sub>See [Getting SyntaxError for print with keyword argument end=' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/) for the opposite problem.</sub>

<sub>See [Python 3 print without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122868) for workarounds, and confirmation that `print` cannot be *made to* work like a statement in Python 3.</sub>

Comment: Note as a special case: **the error message may be different** depending on the exact Python version (more recent versions offer an explicit suggestion `Did you mean print("Hello, World!")?`) and exactly what should be printed (for example, in 3.8, `print int()` simply gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`).

Comment: ([Apparently, very old versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925852) only said `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` even when given a string literal.)

Answer (score 685, accepted):

This error message means that you are attempting to use Python 3 to follow an example or run a program that uses the Python 2 `print` statement:

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

The statement above does not work in Python 3. In Python 3 you need to add parentheses around the value to be printed:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

---

*“SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'”* is a new error message that was added in Python 3.4.2 primarily to help users that are trying to follow a Python 2 tutorial while running Python 3.

In Python 3, printing values changed from being a distinct statement to being an ordinary function call, so it now needs parentheses:

```
>>> print("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
```

In earlier versions of Python 3, the interpreter just reports a generic syntax error, without providing any useful hints as to what might be going wrong:

```
>>> print "Hello, World!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello, World!"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As for *why* `print` became an ordinary function in Python 3, that didn't relate to the basic form of the statement, but rather to how you did more complicated things like printing multiple items to stderr with a trailing space rather than ending the line.

In Python 2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print >> sys.stderr, 1, 2, 3,; print >> sys.stderr, 4, 5, 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(1, 2, 3, file=sys.stderr, end=" "); print(4, 5, 6, file=sys.stderr)
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

Starting with the Python 3.6.3 release in September 2017, some error messages related to the Python 2.x print syntax have been updated to recommend their Python 3.x counterparts:

```
>>> print "Hello!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello!"
                 ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello!")?
```

Since the "Missing parentheses in call to print" case is a compile time syntax error and hence has access to the raw source code, it's able to include the full text on the rest of the line in the suggested replacement. However, it doesn't currently try to work out the appropriate quotes to place around that expression (that's not impossible, just sufficiently complicated that it hasn't been done).

The `TypeError` raised for the right shift operator has also been customised:

```
>>> print >> sys.stderr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"?
```

Since this error is raised when the code runs, rather than when it is compiled, it doesn't have access to the raw source code, and hence uses meta-variables (`<message>` and `<output_stream>`) in the suggested replacement expression instead of whatever the user actually typed. Unlike the syntax error case, it's straightforward to place quotes around the Python expression in the custom right shift error message.

Comment: My thanks to @antti-haapala for adding the summary at the top that directly answers the question before continuing on to the longer explanation of the origins of the error message :)

Comment: I also switched the answer to community wiki, as steadily accumulating further SO rep for this doesn't feel right to me (see http://bugs.python.org/issue21669 for the background on how the error message and this SO question co-evolved)

Comment: Hello! I think this tool can help someone https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: Add the line *from __future__ import print_function* in your 2.7 file to add new python 3 print() lines to your code. Hence the code becomes compatible to 2.7+ and 3.0+

Comment: How do you force the system to use Python 2.7 vs 3? Perhaps this is a good place for it.

Comment: This is a real PITA when you have both 27 ad 37 running on the same box...

Comment: @Praxiteles You can use update-alternatives to set your preferred version of python: `sudo update-alternatives --config python` and set the default version.

Answer (score 37):

Unfortunately, the old [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/353/) isn't completely up to date anymore.

[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python.png]

Since Python 3.0 you have to write:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

And someone has still to write that `antigravity` library :(

Comment: antigravity is there though ... have you tried importing it? ;)

Comment: [AntiGravity Easter Egg](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/import-antigravity.html)

Answer (score 26):

There is a change in syntax from Python 2 to Python 3.
In Python 2,

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

will work but in Python 3, use parentheses as

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

This is equivalent syntax to Scala and near to Java.

Comment: Only those who want to destroy a language will change the syntax to that extent. What was natural to do was to retain both syntax as valid.

Comment: @Bran not at all. It would make absolutely no sense to have one function, in the entire language, that can also be called with an alternate syntax, based on its name. Incidentally, your comment came almost twelve years after the first 3.x release, and after all support (even security fixes) for 2.x had been completely dropped by the dev team (this is after they made a special exception in their usual release schedule to accomodate migration), and at a time when an overwhelming majority of Python developers were already happily using 3.x.

Comment: So much for backwards compability in a programming language. In major use.

Answer (score 15):

In Python 3.x, `print` is now a *function*, rather than a *statement* as it was in 2.x.

Therefore, `print` is used by *calling* it as a function, and thus parentheses are needed:

**Python 2.x**: print "Lord of the Rings"

**Python 3.x**: print("Lord of the Rings")

There are multiple advantages to making `print` a function:

- The `print` function offers more flexibility when printing multiple values (which are now arguments to the function). In particular, it allows for [argument splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847):

```
>>> items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> print(*items, sep='+')
foo+bar+baz
```

- The behavior of calls to `print` can be replaced by simply writing a new function named `print`. This would be impossible with the `print` statement.

Comment: Also, the `print` function can be used as a higher-order function, i.e., passed to other functions. This rarely comes up, however.

Answer (score 8):

If your code should work in both Python 2 and 3, you can achieve this by loading this at the beginning of your program:

```
from __future__ import print_function   # If code has to work in Python 2 and 3!
```

Then you can print in the Python 3 way:

```
print("python")
```

If you want to print something without creating a new line - you can do this:

```
for number in range(0, 10):
    print(number, end=', ')
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in Python3 even with that import. Code is without parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, you can only print as:

```
print("STRING")
```

But in Python 2, the parentheses are not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I could also just add that I knew everything about the syntax change between `Python2.7` and `Python3`, and my code was correctly written as `print("string")` and even 
`print(f"string")`...

But after some time of debugging I realized that my bash script was calling python like:

> python file_name.py

which had the effect of calling my python script by default using `python2.7` which gave the error. So I changed my bash script to:

> python3 file_name.py

which of coarse uses python3 to run the script which fixed the error.

Comment: You could also add a shebang to the top of the file to state which Python to load the file with

Answer (score 3):

`print('Hello, World!')`

You're using python 3, where you need brackets when printing.

Answer (score 3):

So I was getting this error

```
from trp import BoundingBox, Document
File "C:\Users\Kshitij Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\trp\__init__.py", line 31
print ip
      ^ 
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(ip)?
```

This is a Python package error, in which Python2 has been used and you are probably running this on Python3.

One solution could be to convert Python2 `print something` to Python3 `print(something)` for every line in each file in the package folder, which is not a good idea. I mean, you can do it but still there are better ways.

To perform the same task, there is a package named **2to3** in Python which converts Python2 scripts to Python3 scripts. To install it, execute the  command in terminal..

```
pip install 2to3
```

Then change the directory in terminal to the location where the package files are present, in my case - **C:\Users\Kshitij Agarwal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\trp**

Now execute the command

```
2to3 . -w
```

and **voila**, all the *Python2* files in that directory will be converted to *Python3*.

**Note**:- The above commands hold true for other operating systems as well. Only Python package path will vary as per the system.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the direct answers here, one should note the other key difference between python 2 and 3. The [official python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) goes into almost all of the major differences and focuses on when you should use either of the versions. [This blog post](https://learntocodewith.me/programming/python/python-2-vs-python-3/) also does a fine job of explaining the current python universe and the somehow unsolved puzzle of moving to python 3.

As far as I can tell, you are beginning to learn the python language. You should consider the aforementioned articles before you continue down the python 3 route. Not only will you have to change some of your syntax, you will also need to think about which packages will be available to you (an advantage of python 2) and potential optimizations that could be made in your code (an advantage of python 3).

Answer (score 1):

`print "text"` is not the way of printing text in python as this won't work
`print("text")` will print said text on your screen in the command line