# how to find name of friends on facebook in python

Tags: python, facebook

I've tried this code to find name of friends on facebook in python but it's not working

```
import facebook

token='my token'

graph= facebook.GraphAPI(token)

profile=graph.get_object("me")  #extracting your own profile

friends=graph.get_connections("me","friends")['data']

friend_list=[friend['name'] for friend in friends]

print friend_list
```

The error: **SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'**

Comment: can you also include the output (error message or other message) during your execution?

Comment: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: You can only get friends who are users of the same app as well, and have granted it `user_friends` permission too.

Comment: added the error message to your question, because it´s the most important part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this :)

```
token = 'mytoken'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]

print friend_list
```

Comment: already tried same output is coming

Comment: it will work on my system...which python version u r using???

Answer (score 4):

That error means you are using Python 3 with code from Python 2, try this:

```
print(friend_list)
```

Source: [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python/)

Btw, i have no clue about Python (i just inserted the error message into Google), but if `friend_list` is an array, you may want to try this instead:

```
print(', '.join(friend_list))
```

Also, just in case you don´t kow, you can only get access to friends who authorized your App with `user_friends` too. See this thread for more information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)