# Having issues with formatters: "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting this error and I don't understand why.

I'm learning to use Gmail's API and copy pasted their example from: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get#examples

Here is the code:

```
def GetThread(service, user_id, thread_id):
  """Get a Thread.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    thread_id: The ID of the Thread required.

  Returns:
    Thread with matching ID.
  """
  try:
    thread = service.users().threads().get(userId=user_id, id=thread_id).execute()
    messages = thread['messages']
    print ('thread id: %s - number of messages '
           'in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))
    return thread
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

I'm currently getting this error:

```
    thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart1.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart1.py", line 152, in main
    GetThread(service, EMAIL_LOGIN, thread_id)
  File "quickstart1.py", line 121, in GetThread
    'in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Even when I change
`print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))`

to: `print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d') % ('test', 1)`

```
thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart1.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart1.py", line 151, in main
    GetThread(service, EMAIL_LOGIN, thread_id)
  File "quickstart1.py", line 120, in GetThread
    print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d') % ('test', 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

I still get the same error. Any idea reason why?

Comment: You need to move the `)` after `'%d'` to the end of the line.

Comment: any specific reason why you use `%` instead of [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)?

Comment: Keeping this post open would help future visitors that are confused by Google's lack of an explicit Python version statement. Far more people use Python 3 these days, and may run into the same issue. This isn't a typo the OP made.

Comment: OP please see that your code matches the question, you're still having the verbatim-copied print statement in your question, and `except`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place.

```
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d') % ('test', 1)
```

You're calling `print`, which returns `None`. Then you're trying to
apply `%` between that `None` and the tuple. It should be:

```
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d' % ('test', 1))
```

**Edit:** Martijn is right. This is Python 2. I was thinking in terms of
Python 3, that being the only one I use.

If this were in Python 3, `print` would be a function, and parentheses
would have to go around everything. Running this in Python 3 will get
that error.

However, in Python 2, `print` is a statement and you don't have to use
parentheses. Looking at the code you link to, we see this:

```
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages '
       'in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))
```

Here, the parentheses serve a different purpose. The string is split
across two lines, and parentheses are needed to make the parser treat it
as one object; `'strings' 'like' 'this'` are concatenated into one
string. So, in Python 2, this is correct syntax.

Comment: @MorganAllen: no, the Google docs are written for Python 2, not Python 3. There are material differences between those versions. Google could make this more explicit and provide Python 3 examples, perhaps, but that doesn't make their current code wrong.

Answer (score 6):

This example from Google was written for Python 2, but you're using it on Python 3 or with `from __future__ import print_function`. It is very unfortunate that Google is using an obsolete version of Python in their documentation examples, though at least it is obvious from the last `print` statement and the `except Exception, e`, which was changed to `except errors.HttpError, error`:

---

Specifically:

```
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages '
       'in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))
```

was written for Python 2, and should be changed to

```
print(('thread id: %s - number of messages '
       'in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages)))
```

---

In Python 3, `print` is a function that returns `None`, so that kind of statement is parsed as

```
(print('something')) % (something, something)
```

i.e. the operator `%` is applied to the return value of `print` and the tuple `(thread['id'], len(messages))`.

However in Python 2, where `print` was a statement, everything after the `print` keyword would have been evaluated first and printed; so in Python 2, it is parsed as

```
print (('something') % (something, something))
```

Adding the extra parentheses around the whole thing makes it work correctly on Python 3.

---

If the statement didn't have those extra parentheses, you would have got [SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'” mean in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python) which would have made the error immediately obvious.

Comment: Your last paragraph leaves the interesting question why the other `print` statement in the program hasn't generated a SyntaxError before the code got near this point.

Comment: Perhaps the user did get that and knew how to fix it - there.

Comment: @Duncan fixed wording :d

Answer (score 1):

`%` operates on a string, not a print statement/function.

```
# wrong
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d') % (thread['id'], len(messages))

# right
print ('thread id: %s - number of messages in this thread: %d' % (thread['id'], len(messages)))
```

---

It's actually a little more complicated than that. In Python 2, `print` was a statement that took 1 or more expressions and printed them to standard output. A statement like `print ("hi")` was parsed as the `print` keyword followed by a parenthesized expression. That means `print ("%s") % ("hi",)` would be parsed as `print` followed by the expression `("%s") % ("hi,)`, which would evaluated to `"hi"`, then be printed.

In Python 3, `print` became a function, meaning the parser now recognizes `print ("%s") % ("hi", )` as one expression, involving the `%` operator and its two arguments, the function call `print("%s")` and the tuple `("hi",)`. Since `print` returns `None`, Python complains that `%` doesn't support the first argument being of type `None`.