# SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to use pip to install a package, but im getting the above error.
looks like this:

```
print GCC_VERSION
```

obviously it would be `print(GCC_VERSION)` in python 3.5, but how do i get pip to use the python 3.5 print and not python 2.7's?

Comment: you have to use pip3, not pip, unless you are inside a virtual env where pip is aliased to pip

Comment: print("Hello world") link to the full answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python

Answer (score 1):

pip is probably not the problem. Likely, you are trying to install a package meant for Python 2 in Python 3. Check the package for python version, or try installing Python 2 and see if it works then. If you can access the problem file, edit it to replace `print` with `print()`.