# unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Tags: python, json, unsupportedoperation

This is my code:

```
def _parse(self, text):
    """
    This is the core interaction with the parser.

    It returns a Python data-structure, while the parse()
    function returns a JSON object
    """

    # CoreNLP interactive shell cannot recognize newline
    if '\n' in text or '\r' in text:
        to_send = re.sub("[\r\n]", " ", text).strip()
    else:
        to_send = text


    self.corenlp.sendline(to_send)
    max_expected_time = max(300.0, len(to_send) / 3.0)

    # repeated_input = self.corenlp.except("\n")  # confirm it
    t = self.corenlp.expect(["\nNLP> ", pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF,
                                 "\nWARNING: Parsing of sentence failed, possibly because of out of memory."],
                                timeout=max_expected_time)
    incoming = self.corenlp.before
    lag = incoming.split(b"\r\n")
    incoming = b"\r\n".join(lag).decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
    if t == 1:
        # TIMEOUT, clean up anything left in buffer
        print >>sys.stderr, {'error': "timed out after %f seconds" % max_expected_time,
                                 'input': to_send,
                                 'output': incoming}
        raise TimeoutError("Timed out after %d seconds" % max_expected_time)
    elif t == 2:
                # EOF, probably crash CoreNLP process
        print >>sys.stderr, {'error': "CoreNLP terminates abnormally while parsing",
                                 'input': to_send,
                                 'output': incoming}
        raise ProcessError("CoreNLP process terminates abnormally while parsing")
    elif t == 3:
                # out of memory
        print >>sys.stderr, {'error': "WARNING: Parsing of sentence failed, possibly because of out of memory.",
                                 'input': to_send,
                                 'output': incoming}
        raise OutOfMemoryError

    if VERBOSE:
        print("%s\n%s" % ('=' * 40, incoming))
    try:
        results = parse_parser_results(incoming)
    except ixception as e:
        if VERBOSE:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        raise e

    self.pre_loaded_analisys_dict[to_send] = results

    with open(self.pre_analysis,"w", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(self.pre_loaded_analisys_dict,f)

    return results
```

And I've got this error (I'm parsing a lot of terms and it's the first time that I've got that error):

> unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Any Ideas?

EDIT: printint incoming variable i've got this:

> b'Q\r\nAnnotation pipeline timing information:\r\nTokenizerAnnotator:
>   0.0 sec.\r\nWordsToSentencesAnnotator: 0.0 sec.\r\nPOSTaggerAnnotator: 0.0 sec.\r\nMorphaAnnotator: 0.1 sec.\r\nNERCombinerAnnotator: 0.4 sec.\r\nTOTAL: 0.6 sec. for 337 tokens at 606.1
>   tokens/sec.\r\nPipeline setup: 0.0 sec.\r\nTotal time for
>   StanfordCoreNLP pipeline: 138.7 sec.\r\n'

when I should get something like this:

> b'Contusion of knee\r\nSentence #1 (3 tokens):\r\nContusion of
>   knee\r\n[Text=Contusion CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=9
>   PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=contusion NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=of
>   CharacterOffsetBegin=10 CharacterOffsetEnd=12 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=of
>   NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=knee CharacterOffsetBegin=13
>   CharacterOffsetEnd=17 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=knee NamedEntityTag=O] \r'

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: I've got this: 'Annotation pipeline timing information ...'

Answer (score 7):

A belated answer looking for questions where folks have hit this specific error message: it indicates that you're attempting to use Python 2 style stream redirection either in Python 3, or while `from __future__ import print_function` is in effect in Python 2.x.

Instead of writing `print >> sys.stderr, expression`, it's instead necessary to write `print(expression, file=sys.stderr)`.

[What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python/) gives more information on this change.