# python adding space after certain clusters or characters

Tags: python, encryption, vim, separator

I have a text file that looks like the following:

> AELSLAEM A3LYKM
>
> AELSLAEM A3LYKM WRH7MT3 AELLHH WBRKAETHH
>
> HHL TSMH7 LY
>
> LW SMH7T
>
> MN FD9LK
>
> HHL TTKRM A3LY B
>
> MN FD9LK AHRYD
>
> AHNAE AHRYD MN FD9LK
>
> MN FD9LK AHH7D9R LY
>
> HHL LDYK H7JHZ
>
> AENTDH6R QLYLAE
>
> SAHNTDH6R HHNAE
>
> MTAE YGHLQ AELMT6A3M
>
> MTAE YFTH7 AELMT6A3M ...

I would like to add a white space after each of these characters:

> characters = [AH, AE2, UW, EH, AE, B, T3, T, TH, JH, H7, X, D, DH, R, Z, S, SH, S9, D9, T6, DH6, A3, GH, F, Q, K, L, M, N, HH, W, Y, AA, AN, IH, EN, UN, 2]

so the output would look like the following:

> AE L S L AE M A3 L Y K M
>
> AE L S L AE M A3 L Y K M W R H7 M T3 AE L L HH W B R K AE T HH
>
> HH L T S M H7 L Y
>
> L W S M H7 T
>
> M N F D9 L K
>
> HH L T T K R M A3 L Y B
>
> M N F D9 L K AH R Y D

What I am mostly having trouble with is adding space, for example, after D only if it is followed by a digit or H.. I would like to do this in python or (if possible) vim. Could any one help with this. thank you!

Comment: try this,
`for each in characters:
 if each in contents:
  contents = contents.replace(each, each + " ")`

Comment: Thank you Jaimin.. 
here is the script.. I am getting an error!
'inp = open("input.txt", "r")
inp1 = inp.readline()

characters = ['AH', 'AE2', 'UW', 'EH', 'AE', 'B', 'T3', 'T', 'TH', 'JH', 
       'H7', 'X', 'D', 'DH', 'R', 'Z', 'S', 'SH', 'S9', 'D9', 'T6', 
       'DH6', 'A3', 'GH', 'F', 'Q', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'HH', 'W', 
  'Y', 'AA', 'AN', 'IH', 'EN', 'UN', '2']

for each in characters:
 {
      if each in inp1: inp1= inp1.replace(each, each + " ")
  #inp1= inp1.replace(chars, chars + ' ')
  #print inp1

 }'

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: `{` and `}` this shouldn't be there, are you trying to say that your getting error within the parenthesis ?
Use `inp.read() ` instead of `inp.readline() `

Comment: Thank you! it finally worked!
I am however not getting output! I added a print statement in the loop: 'print content' but that gave an error!

Comment: I have post the script as answer. I cannot tell you where you are getting it wrong unless you tell me the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the replace method. So you go through the character array using a for each loop (or regular for loop if you prefer) and say replace all instances of this character with the character plus a space:

```
for chars in characters:
{
    str = str.replace(chars, chars + ' ')
}
```

That's assuming you read in the file into a variable called str.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
import sys

try:
    inp = open("input.txt", "r") 
    inp1 = inp.read()
    inp.close()
except Exception, e:
    print "File error:", e
    sys.exit(-1)

print "\nFile Contents:\n", inp1
characters = ['AH', 'AE2', 'UW', 'EH', 'AE', 'B', 'T3', 'T', 'TH', 'JH', 'H7', 'X', 'D', 'DH', 'R', 'Z', 'S', 'SH', 'S9', 'D9', 'T6', 'DH6', 'A3', 'GH', 'F', 'Q', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'HH', 'W', 'Y', 'AA', 'AN', 'IH', 'EN', 'UN', '2'] 
for each in characters: 
    if each in inp1: 
        inp1= inp1.replace(each, each + " ") 

print "\nOutput:\n", inp1
```

Comment: It does not like the line 7 _except Exception, e:_ I get invalid syntax error **except Exception, e**

Comment: When I use 'as e' instead, I get this error _Syntax error:missing parentheses in call to print_ in the next line: **print "File error:", e**

Comment: @AliAlshehri thats because you are using python 3, I guess. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)