# Python 3.6.0 syntax error "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm a gamer who decided he wanted to make some basic games others could play. I'm very new to coding and have the most basic understanding of it. My cousin and I are trying to make a text based game in Python 3.6.0. We have searched the internet for answers to our problem, but cannot find anything. Code is below:

---

```
def start ():
    print ''' Welcome to the game! Created by Meme Buddha
type 'start' to begin'''
    print
    prompt_sta ()

def prompt_sta ():
    prompt_0 = input ('Type a Command, ')
    try:
        if prompt_0 == 'Start':
            outside_house ()
        elif prompt_0 == 'Begin':
            print 'You need to drink bleach and look at spicy memes!'
            print
            prompt_sta ()
        else:
            print 'Type Start, throw it on him not me,ugh,lets try something else!'
            print
            prompt_sta ()
    except ValueError:
        print 'Type Start, throw it on him not me,ugh,lets try something else!'
        print
        prompt_sta ()

start ()
```

---

When trying to run the module to test it, we get an error which says:

> "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'"

Since we have such a basic knowledge of coding, and couldn't find answers on google, we were hoping that someone could help fix this most likely, simple error.

Comment: maybe take a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: hard to believe that you couldn't find it on google, given that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python has so many upvotes... - and I found it on google using only the error code...

Answer (score 12):

The `print` "statement" in Python 3.x is a function that uses parenthesis so:

```
print "Hello world"  # python 2.x
```

Is now

```
print("Hello world")   # python 3.x
```

Comment: That's technically wrong. There's no print statement in Python 3.x, it's a function call.