# Failed to install wsgiref on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, wsgiref

I have a problem installing `wsgiref`:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

My requirement.txt file are shown as below.

```
numpy==1.8.1
scipy==0.14.0
pyzmq==14.3.1
pandas==0.14.0
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==2.1.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.3
openpyxl==1.8.6
patsy==0.2.1
pyparsing==2.0.2
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.4
scikit-learn==0.14.1
six==1.7.3
tornado==3.2.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
statsmodels==0.5.0
```

when I run `pip install -r requirement.txt`, I got this error

```
Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Using cached wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xs/y0pbzxkn7gqcdtrz4cpxtwrw0000gn/T/pip-build-hkiqbu1j/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
      File "/private/var/folders/xs/y0pbzxkn7gqcdtrz4cpxtwrw0000gn/T/pip-build-hkiqbu1j/wsgiref/ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
        print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xs/y0pbzxkn7gqcdtrz4cpxtwrw0000gn/T/pip-build-hkiqbu1j/wsgiref/
```

I have tried to run `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and `sudo easy_install -U setuptools` but neither works. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this line `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`, I think it needs Python 2.x to run the `setup.py`. Whether to use parentheses in `print` is the different syntax of Python 2 and Python 3.

This is the solution from the [Github issue](https://github.com/skoczen/will/issues/148):

> There are a few fixes that will get you running, in order of least work to most:
>
> 1. Switch over to python2.7 for your will installs.
> 2. Try to upgrade wsgiref with pip install --upgrade wsgiref, and see if the latest version works with your setup, and with will (if it doesn't, you'd notice the http/webhooks stuff not working.
> 3. If you try 2) and it works, submit a PR here with the upgraded version in requirements.txt. (You can find out what versions you've got by using pip freeze).

You can find more about the syntax difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: Remove dependency, use python3's `wsgiref` [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49874665/3202958)

Answer (score 31):

wsgiref is already been included as a standard library in Python 3...
So in case if you are trying with Python 3 just go ahead and import wsgiref thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
**Flask-restful** is deprecated, use version **flask-restx**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).