# Syntax error in google Python guide with Py 3

Tags: python-3.x

Edit: Nevermind Just figured it out

Comment: Please copy the relevant code snippet and the error message as text into your question. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax for print.
In Python 3x , print required statement to be enclosed in parenthesis.

`print('%s got :%s expected :%s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected)))`

Comment: In the error there is no parenthesis for print, send the new error that you are getting after adding parenthesis