# Cloning git in python

Tags: python, git, api

I am trying to clone a git repo in Python but I am getting an invalid syntax error. Here is my code so far:

```
import pickle
import os
if not os.path.exists('secret_petfinder_credentials.pkl'):
Petfinder={}
Petfinder['Consumer Key']='mykey'
Petfinder['Consumer Secret']='mysecret'
   with open('secret_petfinder_credentials.pkl','wb') as f: 
       pickle.dump(Petfinder, f)
else: 
   Petfinder=pickle.load(open('secret_petfinder_credentials.pkl','rb'))
!pip install petfinder
git clone git://github.com/gtaylor/petfinder-api.git`
```

Comment: FYI: to properly post code block mark it and use `{}` button

Comment: Well clearly those last two lines are indeed not valid Python. What makes you think they would be?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to clone from your python script, consider [`GitPython`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), and its [clone_from()](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=clone#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from) function:

```
from git import Repo

Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)
```

Or [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html), and its [`clone_repository()`](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html#pygit2.clone_repository) function.

Comment: I did the following:                                                                                            
   `from git import Repo                                                                                               
    Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/gtaylor/petfinder-api', 'repo_dir1') 
    import petfinder`                                                                                   And am getting an error: Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'

Comment: @SamP Check your version of Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445440/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445440/6309. It should probably be python 2 for the code/example to work.