# Trouble importing module in Python

Tags: python, build, python-import

#### Versions

`OS:       OSX Sierra
Python:   3.5`

#### What am I trying to achieve?

I'm trying to import [krakenex](https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex) and run it with cmd + b in Sublime Text 3 on OSX.

#### What do I expect to happen?

I expect to be able to run [the example open-positions.py](https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex/blob/master/examples/open-positions.py) (or any other).

#### What happens instead?

When pressing cmd + b, I get
"import krakenex
ImportError: No module named krakenex"

If I create a new file that just says "print 'hello world'" and then press cmd + b, it does print 'hello world'.

However, krakenex is not imported when I press cmd + b within open-positions.py.

The problem is probably very basic. I learned python the day before yesterday, installed Anaconda yesterday, and I have very little experience with APIs. Apologies for the incompetence.

I downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex/, extracted it, then ran 
`python3 setup.py install` within that extracted directory. 
I then opened that whole extracted folder with Sublime Text 3. 
Then, within open-positions.py, if I press cmd + b, I get said error message.

The full output is

> raceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Norbert/Downloads/python3-krakenex-master/examples/open-positions.py", line 1, in 
>       import krakenex
>   ImportError: No module named krakenex
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: "python" -u "/Users/Norbert/Downloads/python3-krakenex-master/examples/open-positions.py"]
>   [dir: /Users/Norbert/Downloads/python3-krakenex-master/examples]
>   [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create a new file that just says `print 'hello world'` and then press cmd + b, it does print `hello world`.

Here is your problem. See, your program is written in Python 2. Had you run it in Python 3, it would say [`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python).

You've installed that module into your python3 and are running python2 from ST3.

Comment: Oh, thank you. How do I change it so that I run python3 from ST3? I understand I have both python 2 and 3 installed and krakenex (this version at least) only works with python 3.

Comment: That I do not know directly; I am not a Mac / ST3 user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it. If anyone who happens to read this knows, please let me know how or where to look.

Answer (score 0):

try this  
easy_install krakenex
Or 
pip install krakenex
Or
 read this and follow the doc
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/krakenex

Comment: Thank you. easy_install krakenex throws an error and I don't seem t have   pip installed but I did run "python3 ./setup.py install" as instructed in the docs, and the problem persists.