# How do I make Sublime Text 3 run Python 3 instead of Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, anaconda

I installed Anaconda yesterday and learned python the day before.

When I try to run a script by pressing cmd + b in ST3, I find [this import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404945/trouble-importing-module-in-python/45404975#45404975).

One of the answers to the import error problem suggests the issue is I'm running python2 instead of python3.

How do I change ST3 so that it runs python3 instead of python2?

I found [this directive](https://gist.github.com/Black-Milk/9361651) but I don't know how to find the path or whether it is relevant.

I'm using OSX Sierra.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Code with Python 3.5.0 + Sublime 3.0 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205895/running-code-with-python-3-5-0-sublime-3-0-on-mac) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730866/set-up-python-3-build-system-with-sublime-text-3

Comment: It seems you're right. Thank you.

Comment: You can mark it closed yourself if it answered your question :)

Comment: Thank you. I just confirmed it works and marked it as a duplicate.