# Why are "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" reported as an IndentationError rather than a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, indentation

In Python 3.5.2 and Python 3.6.1, when I try this code:

```
if True:
print "just right!"
```

I get an error like:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print "just right!"
        ^
IndentationError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

This happens both at the REPL and when running the code from a `.py` file.

According to [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439) , it seems like the error should be reported as a `SyntaxError`, not as an `IndentationError`. As explained in the top answer there:

> *“SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'”* is a new error message that was added in Python 3.4.2 primarily to help users that are trying to
> follow a Python 2 tutorial while running Python 3.

That matches the error message I got, but not the exception type.

Is this a bug? If so, what's causing it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in 3.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IndentationError` is a subclass of `SyntaxError`, so technically, this *is* a syntax error being raised.

You have *two* errors here. Both the indentation is wrong *and* you are missing parentheses. It's a bit of a bug, there is code that alters the `SyntaxError` message when the `print` special case is detected, and that code still applies for subclasses of `SyntaxError` (it is applied in the `SyntaxError` exception constructor).

You can trigger the same error for the `TabError` exception:

```
>>> compile('if 1:\n    1\n\tprint "Look ma, tabs!"', '', 'single')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "", line 3
    print "Look ma, tabs!"
                         ^
TabError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

The `SyntaxError` codepath checking for the `exec()` and `print()` edge-cases should really only fire for actual `SyntaxError` instances, not subclasses, as that's just confusing.

I've filed [issue 31161](http://bugs.python.org/issue31161) to track this.

Comment: So you're saying this is intended behavior?

Comment: @ChristianDean: not quite, I'll see if this is filed as a bug yet.

Comment: _"You have two errors here. "_ - But if I have to two errors here, doesn't Python usually say something like "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"?

Comment: @ChristianDean: it's one exception, but there are two syntax errors. The `SyntaxError` constructor is designed to detect special cases, but misfires here.

Comment: It appears that your own patch for the issue was accepted into 3.6.3. Would it be appropriate to edit to make note of that?