# Printing without parentheses varying error message using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-internals

When I try to use `print` without parentheses on a simple name in Python 3.4 I get:

```
>>> print max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    print max
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Ok, now I get it, I just forgot to port my Python 2 code.

But now when I try to print the result of a function:

```
>>> print max([1,2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    print max([1,2])
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or:

```
print max.__call__(23)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(Note that the cursor is pointing to the character before the first dot in that case.)

The message is different (and slightly misleading, since the marker is below the `max` function).

Why isn't Python able to detect the problem earlier?

Note: This question was inspired by the confusion around this question: *[Pandas read.csv syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184208/pandas-read-csv-syntax-error)*, where a few Python experts missed the real issue because of the misleading error message.

Comment: I noticed something similar before with string formatting e.g. `print '{}'.format('hi')`

Comment: Interesting that the "missing parentheses" message is special-cased in a not-quite-special-enough way.

Comment: I wonder if you could collect some data on how varied it is each execution... I have a feeling it's python's way of reading in class identifiers. A very interesting question though.

Comment: @kindall I suspect that you're right: the "missing parentheses" is a kludge to make sure users understand in most basic cases, but it's unable to work on every case because of the generic python 3 parsing (which is also the reason why `print` was converted to a function)

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, edited & fixed

Comment: I think this error message is produced in some simple cases only as help for the user. `def x(): print max` (single line) for example does not produce the missing parenthesis hint. and `lambda x: print x` seems to have a bug and print `Did you mean print(x: print x)` which isn't even valid python.

Comment: `exceptions.c` has a comment ".. The error message can be a bit odd in cases where the "arguments" are
 * completely illegal syntactically, but that isn't worth the hassle of
 * fixing." for the function `_set_legacy_print_statement_msg`, which prints the only occurrence of that particular error.

Comment: (Discussed in https://bugs.python.org/issue21669. Guido van Rossum: "Don't change the grammar, just hack the heck out of the error message.")

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445440/2564301

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for `exceptions.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f8a4c03ede6048022f60a58d5a21b278b78a8a16/Objects/exceptions.c), right above `_set_legacy_print_statement_msg` there's this nice block comment:

```c
/* To help with migration from Python 2, SyntaxError.__init__ applies some
 * heuristics to try to report a more meaningful exception when print and
 * exec are used like statements.
 *
 * The heuristics are currently expected to detect the following cases:
 *   - top level statement
 *   - statement in a nested suite
 *   - trailing section of a one line complex statement
 *
 * They're currently known not to trigger:
 *   - after a semi-colon
 *
 * The error message can be a bit odd in cases where the "arguments" are
 * completely illegal syntactically, but that isn't worth the hassle of
 * fixing.
 *
 * We also can't do anything about cases that are legal Python 3 syntax
 * but mean something entirely different from what they did in Python 2
 * (omitting the arguments entirely, printing items preceded by a unary plus
 * or minus, using the stream redirection syntax).
 */
```

So there's some interesting info. In addition, in the `SyntaxError_init` method in the same file, we can see

```c
    /*
     * Issue #21669: Custom error for 'print' & 'exec' as statements
     *
     * Only applies to SyntaxError instances, not to subclasses such
     * as TabError or IndentationError (see issue #31161)
     */
    if ((PyObject*)Py_TYPE(self) == PyExc_SyntaxError &&
            self->text && PyUnicode_Check(self->text) &&
            _report_missing_parentheses(self) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
```

Note also that the above references [issue #21669 on the python bugtracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue21669) with some discussion between the author and Guido about how to go about this. So we follow the rabbit (that is, `_report_missing_parentheses`) which is at the very bottom of the file, and see...

```
legacy_check_result = _check_for_legacy_statements(self, 0);
```

However, there are some cases where this is bypassed and the normal `SyntaxError` message is printed, see [MSeifert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185247/5087436) for more about that. If we go one function up to `_check_for_legacy_statements` we *finally* see the *actual check* for legacy print statements.

```c
/* Check for legacy print statements */
if (print_prefix == NULL) {
    print_prefix = PyUnicode_InternFromString("print ");
    if (print_prefix == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
}
if (PyUnicode_Tailmatch(self->text, print_prefix,
                        start, text_len, -1)) {

    return _set_legacy_print_statement_msg(self, start);
}
```

So, to answer the question: "Why isn't Python able to detect the problem earlier?", I would say the problem with parentheses isn't what is detected; it is actually parsed *after* the syntax error. It's a syntax error the whole time, but the actual minor piece about parentheses is caught afterwards just to give an additional hint.

Comment: But it doesn't even go in the `_check_for_legacy_statements` in the mentioned case because an even earlier check in `_report_missing_parentheses` checks for any opening parens and if it finds any it already returns from that function (See also my answer).

Answer (score 17):

The special exception message for `print` used as statement instead of as function is actually implemented as a *special case*.

Roughly speaking when a `SyntaxError` is created it calls a special function that checks for a `print` *statement* based on the *line* the exception refers to.

However, the first test in this [function (the one responsible for the "Missing parenthesis" error message)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/exceptions.c#L2956-L2997) is if there is any opening parenthesis in the line. I copied the source code for that function (CPython 3.6.4) and I marked the relevant lines with "arrows":

```c
static int
_report_missing_parentheses(PySyntaxErrorObject *self)
{
    Py_UCS4 left_paren = 40;
    Py_ssize_t left_paren_index;
    Py_ssize_t text_len = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(self->text);
    int legacy_check_result = 0;

    /* Skip entirely if there is an opening parenthesis <---------------------------- */
    left_paren_index = PyUnicode_FindChar(self->text, left_paren,
                                          0, text_len, 1);
    if (left_paren_index < -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (left_paren_index != -1) {
        /* Use default error message for any line with an opening parenthesis <------------ */
        return 0;
    }
    /* Handle the simple statement case */
    legacy_check_result = _check_for_legacy_statements(self, 0);
    if (legacy_check_result < 0) {
        return -1;

    }
    if (legacy_check_result == 0) {
        /* Handle the one-line complex statement case */
        Py_UCS4 colon = 58;
        Py_ssize_t colon_index;
        colon_index = PyUnicode_FindChar(self->text, colon,
                                         0, text_len, 1);
        if (colon_index < -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (colon_index >= 0 && colon_index < text_len) {
            /* Check again, starting from just after the colon */
            if (_check_for_legacy_statements(self, colon_index+1) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That means it won't trigger the "Missing parenthesis" message if there is **any opening parenthesis** in the line. That leads to the general `SyntaxError` message even if the opening parenthesis is in a comment:

```
print 10  # what(
    print 10  # what(
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Note that the cursor position for two names/variables separated by a white space is always the end of the second name:

```
>>> 10 100
    10 100
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> name1 name2
    name1 name2
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> name1 name2([1, 2])
    name1 name2([1, 2])
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So it is no wonder the cursor points to the `x` of `max`, because it's the last character in the second name. Everything that follows the second name (like `.`, `(`, `[`, ...) is ignored, because Python already found a `SyntaxError`, and it doesn't need to go further, because nothing could make it valid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm not understanding something, but I don't see why Python should point out the error earlier. `print` is a regular function, that is a variable referencing a function, so these are all valid statements:

```
print(10)
print, max, 2
str(print)
print.__doc__
[print] + ['a', 'b']
{print: 2}
```

As I understand it, the parser needs to read the next full token after `print` (`max` in this case) in order to determine whether there is a syntax error. It cannot just say "fail if there is no open parenthesis", because there are a number of different tokens that may go after `print` depending on the current context.

I don't think there is a case where `print` may be directly followed by another identifier or a literal, so you could argue that as soon as there is one letter, a number or quotes you should stop, but that would be mixing the parser's and the lexer's job.

Answer (score 5):

in additions to those excellent answers, without even looking at the source code, we could have guessed that the `print` special error message was a kludge:

so:

```
print dfjdkf
           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

but:

```
>>> a = print
>>> a dsds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    a dsds
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

even if `a == print` but at that stage, it isn't evaluated yet, so you get the generic invalid syntax message instead of the hacked `print` syntax message, which proves that there's a kludge when the first token is `print`.

another proof if needed:

```
>>> print = None
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    print a
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

in that case `print == None`, but the specific message still appears.