# receiving "There is an error in your program: invalid syntax"

Tags: python

```
print("      This is the test for floyds formation     ")

def flyod(n):
    a=1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(i):
            print(a,end=" ")
            a+=1
        print()   
    print()
n=input("Enter the number of rows baby : ")
flyod(n)
```

Getting syntax error on end=" " receiving "There is an error in your program: invalid syntax"

Comment: Python 2, perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running your code with Python 2 as opposed to Python 3, where [`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) and not a statement.

Try running your code as such on your terminal:

```
$ python3 file.py
```

Where `file.py` is obviously replaced as the name of your file.

You might need to install Python 3.

---

If Python 3 is not an option for whatever reason, you *can* use `print` as a function [by importing it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("Hello!", end=" ")
Hello! >>>
```

Note that this will need to be done (the import statement) immediately at the top of your file.