# 'End of statement expected' in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

[image: Why am I getting this error]

Why am I getting this error (see linting) saying **'End of statement expected'** in pycharm?

Comment: If `python 3`, then try `print(x)`

Comment: Yes I am using python 3.x and that worked. Thank you! @student Please add this as answer, I will accept

Comment: In python 3.x you have to use print(x). Read the differences between python 2.x and python 3.x on net

Comment: For details you can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python/25445440#25445440

Comment: This looks like duplicate to link above not sure if you can mark it duplicate.

Comment: How can I mark a question duplicate?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try print with parenthesis in Python3 i.e. `print(x)` instead of `print x`