# Kali Linux Installing Bluto

Tags: linux, pip, kali-linux

Could somebody help me with the following problem? It would be much appreciated.

**Goal** : To install Bluto on Kali Linux 2020.1 using `sudo pip install bluto` command

**Problem** : Install does not complete

**Error message:**

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pdfminer import __version__
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9scbuzrf/pdfminer/pdfminer/__init__.py", line 5
        print __version__ 
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(__version__)? 
    ---------------------------------------- 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Im running : 
Kali Linux 2020.1
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan 19 2020, 22:34:33) 
git version 2.25.0
pip 20.0.2 from /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

**Screenshot**

[Bluto Kali Linux install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jhm4.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

```
print __version__
```

Is python 2x syntax and not compatible with python 3x. You are using 3.8, so it is incompatible.

In your case, `bluto` seems to have `pdfminer==20140328` as a requirement, which is written with python 2x syntax. Note that also `bluto` itself is only compatible with python 2x.

What you can do is:

- Use a python 2 interpreter with `bluto` - since python2 is deprecated, this is not a very good option
- Download the source code of bluto, remove the `pdfminer==20140328` and update the code to python 3
- try to use something like [this three year old fork](https://github.com/Python3pkg/Bluto) that claims to have converted `bluto` to python 3

Comment: yes, bluto github page states at the last line: "Please be aware that the current version of Bluto does not support Python 3. It is a python 2.7.x application."