# To run Port Scanner: (Via Terminal)

Tags: python, node.js, pip

I faced some issue while setting up the project.The python src/scanner.py command was not running properly it shows some error I will attach the screenshot below according to the README.MD file in github I install all the dependencies and start running Port Scanner Via Terminal as mentioned below.

- The first step is Open terminal and type **npm install**: This will
  install the dependencies (Express).
- In the same terminal and type **npm start**: This will start multiple
  servers within the given range.
- Open another terminal and type **python src/scanner.py**: Enter
  localhost or 127.0.0.1. It will scan all the ports and print the open
  ports. At this step I got stuck it shows some error in my terminal
  and not working properly according to the documentation.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kVg3.png)

Comment: you are attempting to use Python 3 to run a program that uses the Python 2 print statement. just run with python 2

Answer (score 0):

follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python). you are running app that used python2 with python3 :) just try to run with python2