# How to print hello world in python?

Tags: python

I tried running a python script:
`print "Hello, World!"`
but I get this error.

```
 File "hello.py", line 1 print "Hello, World!" ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is going on?

Comment: Voting to close - duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The code you are writing is Python 2.x code, but your environment seems like Python 3.0.

here is code for python 3.x

```
print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score -1):

'Hello world' you can print hello world in similar manner

Comment: I think you are confusing the Python interactive interpreter with a script. Echoing a string object is **not the same thing as printing**.