# Printing SHA256 digest result in Python using PyCryptodome library

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I'm following example from PyCryptodome documentation.
https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/sha256.html

[image]

Somehow, I'm facing error when I execute the script below.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't spot what wrong in the script.

Comment: You are using the Python 2 `print` syntax.

Comment: You can try change to "print(h.hexdigest())" from print h.hexdigest().

Comment: @SuperStar, it works perfectly now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: @Pi-Turn. Okay. Good luck.

Comment: When you are posting code, pleas enter it into the actual message not as an image.