# Python IMAP Syntaxerror

Tags: python, imap

Hi I am getting this error when running script. I dont know whats wron with code.

```
File "C:\Users\User\outlook.py", line 25
    print "---------------------------------------------------------"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("---------------------------------------------------------")?
```

```
import imaplib
import email

word = ["http://", "https://", "www.", ".com", "deutschesexkontakte.com"] #list of strings to search for in email body

#connection to the email server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
mail.login('email@outlook.com', 'password')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("Inbox", readonly=True) # connect to inbox.

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search and return uids instead

ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]

result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)') # fetch the email headers and body (RFC822) for the given ID


raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw headers and html and body of the whole email
# including headers and alternate payloads

print "---------------------------------------------------------"
print "Are there links in the email?"
print "---------------------------------------------------------"

msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
for part in msg.walk():
    # each part is a either non-multipart, or another multipart message
    # that contains further parts... Message is organized like a tree
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        plain_text = part.get_payload()
        print plain_text # prints the raw text
        if any(word in plain_text for word in word):
            print '****'
            print 'found link in email body'
            print '****'
        else:
            print '****'
            print 'no link in email body'
            print '****'`
```

Comment: Python 2 code run with python 3?

Comment: You might want to remove your personal data from the code including credentials and website preferences.

Comment: You will also want to use email_from_bytes() with python 3.  You should probably try to find a more modern sample.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: Hi!  These credentials are Bulk Emails, How ever, Thanks for you help! Is it a big deal to rewrite this code to python3?

Answer (score 1):

You need replace **print** from:

```
print "---------"
```

to:

```
print("---------")
```

And with another print too.

Comment: Exactly.  `print x` is Python 2 syntax.  It doesn't work in Python 3.