# pyodbc error: missing parenthesis in call to print

Tags: python, pyodbc

please advise what went wrong in my codes:

im trying to connect to odbc and retrieve data but i failed

```
conn = po.connect(
                DRIVER='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
                SYSTEM = AS400,                
                DBQ = DBQ,
                DFTPKGLIB= 'QGPL',
                LANGUAGEID='ENU',
                PKG = 'QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM)',
                UID=UID,
                PWD=PWD)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT mmnmbtp.FXCLN FROM mmnmbtp")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

I am getting the below error:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-c2fd1d8f7233>", line 52
    print row
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: in python3 you need to use parentheses for prints. `print(row)`

Comment: Duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445439/4985099

Comment: If you are following tutorial material that led you into this problem, it would be better to find a tutorial that's less out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's python version 3.x that you are using, the line saying `print row` should be `print(row)` instead.