# Showing error while creating app using Ionic

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Here is the code

```
E:\Programming\Android app development>ionic start Demo blank --type ionic1
√ Preparing directory .\Demo in 2.92ms
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter in 1.80s
? Integrate your new app with Capacitor to target native iOS and Android? Yes
> ionic integrations enable capacitor --quiet -- Demo io.ionic.starter
> npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\Programming\\Android app development\\Demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` f`enter code here`ailed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Programming\\Android app development\\Demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-10T07_18_12_049Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

      Ionic Enterprise, platform and solutions for teams by Ionic

                  Powerful library of native APIs
                 A supercharged platform for teams

         Learn more: https://ion.link/enterprise

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


> npm.cmd i
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\Programming\\Android app development\\Demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Programming\\Android app development\\Demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Programming\Android app development\Demo\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\samprithazra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-10T07_18_59_237Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

E:\Programming\Android app development>
```

How to fix this? I am running Nodejs 16.13.1 in Windows 10 64bit.
I think maybe it is the problem of Nodejs version. But from my side i haven't found anything wrong. I will glad to know if anything is wrong there.

Comment: make sure u have the recommended node js version

Comment: How to check that recommended node js version

Comment: `https://nodejs.org/en/` , downlaod the LTS which is the recommended version, and make sure u have capacitor compatibale with it, so best situation is to uninstall ionic then download it again with capacitor @latest since for sure it will be compatibale with the recomended nodejs

Comment: you added the ionic1 flag.  That would have to use very old packages and I am sure Node 16 is not support for AngularJS.   You need to Dockerize this and use like Node 6 if you want to use Ionic v1.

Comment: I have now fixed this issue I used node js 14.16.1.Then it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies) relies on [GYP](https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/UserDocumentation.md) which runs on [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)).
You need to make sure your python version installed in your system is compatible with your GYP version.

Your build fails due to the following Python error during GYP execution:

```
import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

This is a [very classic issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python) which usually means you're trying to run a python2.x script with python3.x interpreter.

You need to ensure that node version, gyp version and python version are all compatible.

Currently you're trying to build with :

- node v16.13.1
- gyp v3.8.0
- python v3.x?

GYP only supports Python 3.x starting in v5.0.5 I believe. You need to either update GYP & NPM or use python2.7.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by downgrading my Node js version to 14.16.1.Thanks for your answer