# Why does Python's sockets module show a port as closed even though nmap shows it as open?

Tags: python, nmap, python-sockets

I am learning port scanning through a Udemy course.

Afer finding the open port 445 using Nmap:

[image]

The video from the course asked us to change the port in the code we created accordingly

[image]

And after saving the change, we should execute it with

```
./[NAME]
```

In the video, it shows "Port is open". But when I do it, I get "Port is closed" even though Nmap shows it is open:

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong?

PS: I keep getting the syntax error even though the code I created is identical to the one in the video.

Comment: As for the syntax error about `print`, the video/course must be using Python 2 while you are using Python 3 where `print` is now a function and must be used like a function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445439/2745495

Answer (score -1):

replace the line with the print statement with:
`print(f"port: {port} is closed")`